# unable to log in after tinkering with drivers

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, login, steam

I was having some trouble getting steam to work on my ubuntu installation, while doing this I followed some suggestions about deleting/changing various files and changed a few packages. At some point a message about broken packages came up but I didn't really take notice. I also upgraded to the latest nvidea drivers and deleted some files. Now when I log in I get a weird stripe pattern and am thrown back to the login screen.

Any idea how to get back to a working system? (and anyone know how to fix the steam mess?).

Comment: You didn't say how you installed the NV Drivers. Unless I shut down the various components of X it's most likely to destroy the GUI. I'd open a text TTY, shut down the GUI, and reinstall the Drivers without deleting any files. Do you have anything that apt-get can repair?

Answer (score 3):

You can easily fix it.

Press Ctrl+Alt+F1. login to console and run

```
sudo apt-get purge 'nvidia.*'
```

That will remove Nvidia drivers.

Then you can install some driver, like

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352
```

Then reboot

```
sudo reboot
```

Comment: Based on this answer I started my system, pressed ctrl-alt-f1 and entered my user name and password. I then tried to purge nvidia but it gave me an error that dpkg was not configured properly. I then entered dpkg --configure -a and after rebooting it worked fine. Just reporting this if anyone else has this problem.